# Как получить src загружаемого изображения html js?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Пожалуйста, подскажите фрагмент кода который получает из `<input type="file">` ссылку на изображение, которую можно тут же засунуть в `<img/>`
Желательно сделайте это на jQuery. Спасибо.

Comment: С [прошлым вопросом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1302188) бы разобрались, там кстати и ответ есть на ваш текущий вопрос.

Comment: @De.Minov мне для начало непосредственно с загрузкой разобратся. потом посмотрю на код из твоего ответа на предыдущий  вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Без Jquery

```js
imgInp.onchange = evt => {
  let file = imgInp.files[0];
  
  if (file)
      someImg.src = URL.createObjectURL(file); 
}
```

```html
<input accept="image/*" type='file' id="imgInp" />
<img id="someImg" src="#" alt="your image" />
```

Замечу, что тут не повешены слушатели как это привычно. Так что если нужно - сделайте это.